# How to shade a region using Filling function

Tags: filling

I have two following functions:

```
g21n = √(253349/60000 - g1^2 + 14801/(9375000 2^(2/3) (170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625 + √(4 (-(19374117772816/390625) - (57976501248 g1^2)/625)^3 + (170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625)^2))^(1/3)) + (605441173 2^(1/3))/(9375 (170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625 + √(4 (-(19374117772816/390625) - (57976501248 g1^2)/625)^3 + (170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625)^2))^(1/3)) + (75490236 2^(1/3)g1^2)/(625 (170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625 + √(4 (-(19374117772816/390625) - (57976501248 g1^2)/625)^3 + (170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625)^2))^(1/3)) + (1/(768 2^(1/3)))((170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625 + √(4 (-(19374117772816/390625) - (57976501248 g1^2)/625)^3 + (170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625)^2))^(1/3)))
g22n = √(253349/60000 - g1^2 - 2088267/(6250000 2^(2/3) (170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625 + √(4 (-(19374117772816/390625) - (57976501248 g1^2)/625)^3 + (170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625)^2))^(1/3)) - (302719024 2^(1/3))/(9375 (170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625 + √(4 (-(19374117772816/390625) - (57976501248 g1^2)/625)^3 + (170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625)^2))^(1/3)) + (299124874 I 2^(1/3))/(3125 Sqrt[3] (170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625 + √(4 (-(19374117772816/390625) - (57976501248 g1^2)/625)^3 + (170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625)^2))^(1/3)) + (2088267 I Sqrt[3])/(6250000 2^(2/3) (170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625 + √(4 (-(19374117772816/390625) - (57976501248 g1^2)/625)^3 + (170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625)^2))^(1/3)) + (47922 I 2^(1/3)Sqrt[3])/(125 (170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625 + √(4 (-(19374117772816/390625) - (57976501248 g1^2)/625)^3 + (170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625)^2))^(1/3)) - (37745118 2^(1/3)g1^2)/(625 (170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625 + √(4 (-(19374117772816/390625) - (57976501248 g1^2)/625)^3 + (170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625)^2))^(1/3)) + (37745118 I 2^(1/3) Sqrt[3]g1^2)/(625 (170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625 + √(4 (-(19374117772816/390625) - (57976501248 g1^2)/625)^3 + (170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625)^2))^(1/3)) - (1/(1536 2^(1/3)))((170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625 + Sqrt[4 (-(19374117772816/390625) - (57976501248 g1^2)/625)^3 + (170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625)^2])^(1/3)) - (1/(512 2^(1/3) Sqrt[3]))I (170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625 + Sqrt[4 (-(19374117772816/390625) - (57976501248 g1^2)/625)^3 + (170554388570595993728/244140625 - (255189599799201792 g1^2)/78125 - (190911920799744 g1^4)/625)^2])^(1/3))
```

Plotting both `g21n` and `g22n` as a function of `g1` with the `Filling` command:

```
Plot[{g21n, g22n}, {g1, 0, 10}, FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(g\), \(1\)]\)", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(g\), \(2\)]\)"}, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 6}}, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue], Directive[Orange]}, ImageSize -> Medium, LabelStyle -> {20, Black, Bold}, AspectRatio -> 1, WorkingPrecision -> 20, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black], FrameLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(g\), \(2\)]\)", Italic, Bold, Black, 12], Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(g\), \(1\)]\)", Italic, Bold, Black, 12]}, FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black, Bold], Filling -> {1 -> {Axis, Green}, 2 -> {Axis, White}} AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotPoints -> 100, WorkingPrecision -> 20, Exclusions -> None]
```

Gives
[image]

I  want the region bounded by the two curves to be shaded but it remains unshaded even with the `Filling` command. How should I go about filling the region between the two curves?

**Edit**: Fixed the brackets for `g21n`

Comment: some parentheses are missing in the definition of `g21n`.

Comment: Try `Filling -> {1 -> {2}}`

Comment: @kglr Fixed the parentheses. Sorry about that.

Comment: @CarlWoll There are some leftover, unfilled white spaces when I do `Filling -> {1 -> {2}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `{g21n, Max[0, Re@g22n]}` as the first argument of `Plot` with the option `Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Green}}`:

[image]

Comment: That's great! But there's a tail end coming out of the cusp and I don't want to show that. What should I do to get rid of it ?

Comment: @kowalski, i will update with a fix.

Answer (score 2):

I had an epiphany, keep the argument of `Plot` as `{g21n, g22n}` and just do `Filling -> {{1 -> {Axis, Gray}}, {2 -> {Axis, White}}}`
[image]

Comment: This won't work if the background is not white. For example, if you wanted to overlay this graphic on top of an image, you would have to use something like @kglr's answer.

Comment: I will just do `{2 -> {Axis, "Background color"}}` assuming I know the color that I'm overlaying on. Either way, @kglr works just as well, but I need a cusp to be evident between the blue and orange curve. But still, thanks!